# Why restart of a failed Job fails, though Failed element has been configured?

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to configure restart cabability when the job fails in certain step , then after fixing the problem, it should be able to continue from the failed step on restart.  But it is not happening. Please find my code below.  What am I missing here?.

```
<job id="OneJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" restartable="true">
<listeners>
<listener ref="jobStatusListener" />
</listeners>

<step id="aA" next="bB">
 <tasklet>
     <chunk commit-interval="1000" reader="o_reader" writer="o_writer" />
 </tasklet>
<listeners> <listener ref="stStepListener" /> </listeners>
</step>

<step id="bB" parent="aA">
 <tasklet>
   <chunk commit-interval="1000" reader="t_reader" writer="t_writer" />
</tasklet>
<fail on="FAILED" exit-code="EARLY TERMINATION"/>  
<next on="*" to="cC"/>       
<listeners> <listener ref="stStepListener" /> </listeners>
</step>

<step id="cC">
 <tasklet>
   <chunk commit-interval="1000" reader="th_reader" writer="th_writer" />
 </tasklet>
<listeners> <listener ref="stStepListener" /> </listeners>
</step>
</job>
```

On step 2 it is failing (making a test fail with incorrect read syntax query) and storing the status as

```
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.STATUS= FAILED  
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.EXIT_CODE=EARLY TERMINATION
```

After fixing the problem, When I restart with same job parameter, it is failing and storing the status as

```
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.STATUS= FAILED  
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.EXIT_CODE=FAILED
```

and I see exception as below

org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly

```
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:140)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
at com.one.batch.oneBatchStarter.main(oneBatchStarter.java:33)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=oneJob at state=oneJob.aA with exception

```
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:174)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
... 5 more



Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot construct java.util.Map$Entry : java.util.Map$Entry : Cannot construct java.util.Map$Entry : java.util.Map$Entry
 ---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot construct java.util.Map$Entry : java.util.Map$Entry
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException
cause-message       : Cannot construct java.util.Map$Entry : java.util.Map$Entry
class               : java.util.Map$Entry
required-type       : java.util.Map$Entry
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /map/map/entry
line number         : -1
class[1]            : java.util.HashMap
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter
version             : 1.4.7
-------------------------------
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverte
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Please edit your original question with the full stack trace.

Comment: Is restarted of failed job possible as per the spring batch document?

Comment: Yes.  If a job fails and is configured to be restartable (the default), then you can launch the same job instance again.

Comment: Initially I was using my own custom main class . I was executing & reexecuting it in eclipse.  I thot that could be the reason I couldn't succeed.                                                                                                             So now I tried in command line using CommandLineRunner with restart parameter also. But it again failed on restart of the failed job.    can you please suggest what could be wrong in the configuration?

Comment: From further analysis, I could see in commandLineJobRunner, the JobExplorer is null which causes the failure. And it was not configured in the xml. I did configure in xml but still its failing with exceptions.....  com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot construct java.util.Map$Entry : java.util.Map$Entry : Cannot construct java.util.Map$Entry : java.util.Map$Entry

Comment: This remains an unsolved problem to me. I couldn't able to solve it. Anyone succeeds or has sample example. Please provide.